# How to restore bluetooth connection on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have xamarin project. I would like to pair bluetooth button with an app and keep connection alive in suspended state. I successfully subscribed to characteristic event which represent the click in foreground state. The main use case is to handle the event in suspended state and send data to a server.

I read the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW14), but I am having the difficulties implement restoring the CBCentralManager especially translating these methods into Xamairn.iOS.

**Opt In to State Preservation and Restoration**

```
myCentralManager =
    [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil
     options:@{ CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:
     @"myCentralManagerIdentifier" }];
```

**Reinstantiate Your Central and Peripheral Managers**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSArray *centralManagerIdentifiers =
        launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey];
    ...
```

**Implement the Appropriate Restoration Delegate Method**

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
  willRestoreState:(NSDictionary *)state {

NSArray *peripherals =
    state[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey];
...
```

**Questions:**

1. Does app handle the events in suspended state? (technically in backgrounded)
2. Do I have to reconnect the device after app gets restored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find the answer in the document.

> 1.Does app handle the events in suspended state? (technically in
>   backgrounded)

You need to enable a `Core Bluetooth background execution mode` in the `info.plist` to ensure your app keep running in background.

Also, an iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0 must include in its `Info.plist` file the usage description keys for the types of data it needs to access or it will crash. [InfoPlistKeyReference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW20)

You can read: [Core Bluetooth Background Execution Modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW7)

> 2.Do I have to reconnect the device after app gets restored?

If you `gets restored` here means you `restart your app`, I think you need to reconnect since it will lose the connection after the app is terminated.

If you `gets restored` here means `enter foreground` from `background`, I don't think you need to reconnect if you enabled background mode as your app is still running in the background.

Comment: My biggest concern is suspended state. Let's say app is in suspended state and user clicks the button. Does WillRestoreState event is called after the click (this means subscribed characteristic)? Do I have to reconnect button and subscribe the events?

Comment: @JanNepraš If you enabled background mode, the app is still running in background as in foreground. In my opinion, I don't think you need to reconnect. For `WillRestoreState`,  I find the description [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518819-centralmanager?language=objc), it says this is invoked when the central manager is about to be restored by the system. I still don't think it will be invoked. However, you'd better to do a test and I just give you my opinion through my experience and documents.

Comment: I am still not able to resolve it. Especially the case when device gets out of range then the device is not reconnecting

Comment: @JanNepraš How do you reconnect? I saw other people do scanning after losing connect. And in the method [discoveredperipheral](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/corebluetooth.cbcentralmanagerdelegate.discoveredperipheral), you can compare the discovered peripheral's name with your peripheral's name, if they are the same, you can do connect to that peripheral. [centralmanager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518937-centralmanager?language=objc)